# Why this snippet throws unexpected token?

Tags: javascript

The below snippet throws unexpected token at line: b: function (func, data1)
https://jsbin.com/qobicahica/edit?html,js,output

```
var Funcb = (function()
{
return 
{
    b: function (func, data1)
    {
        alert(1);
    }
};
    })();

Funcb.b(1,1);
```

But, a similar example in below tutorial works:

https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

```
    // define module
    var Module = (function () {
  return {
    myMethod: function () {
      console.log('myMethod has been called.');
    }
  };
})();

// call module + methods
Module.myMethod();
```

EDIT:
Works after removing linebreaks after return, But why?
When javascript is so forgiving and loosely typed, **then why is this not ignored**?:

```
var Funcb = (function()
    {
    return{
        b: function (func, data1)
        {
            alert(1);
        }
    };
        })();
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L01k684r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the third line, a semicolon is inserted after the return statement. See the [rules for JS automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

Remove the newline character after `return` and it should work.

```
var Funcb = (function() {
    return {
        b: function (func, data1) {
            alert(1);
        }
    };
})();

Funcb.b(1,1);
```

To answer your **EDIT**, see page 28 of the [specs](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf).

> The source
>
> ```
> return
> a+b
> ```
>
> is transformed by automatic semicolon insertion into the following:
>
> ```
> return;
> a+b;
> ```
>
> The expression a+b is not treated as a value to be returned by the
>   return statement,  because  a  LineTerminator separates it from the
>   token  return.

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement should contain something. The curly brace is on the next line and should be next to the return statement. This is giving the unexpected token error.

```
var Funcb = (function() {
    return {
        b: function (func, data1) {
           alert(1);
        }
    };
})();
Funcb.b(1,1);
```

Comment: Thanks for checking. Found after posting, edited the question. When javascript is so forgiving and loosely typed, then why this is not ignored?

Comment: Because in your example the function is returning null (an empty return statement), and then the parser tries to evaluate the {b: func..} object which is not assigned.